# Typescript array manipulation/flattening

Tags: angular, firebase

I need to rearrange an array I've retrieved from Firebase, and I've run out of ideas for searching - I'm not quite sure what technique I'm looking for.

I have a firebase project, where each user's reports are stored under a document named by their Firebase auth uid.

```
reports{
        uid{
           reports[
                   {county: "Tipp", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2, ...}
                   {county: "Clare", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2, ...}
                   {county: "Cork", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2, ...}
                  ]
            }
       }
```

I display this in a Mat table, but the problem comes when deleting an entry. I need the UID to pass to the delete function.

Using this function, I can get both the UID and the reports.

```
this.reports =  docs.map(item => {

    return {
      id:  item.payload.doc.id,
      ...item.payload.doc.data()
    };

  });
```

This sets "reports" array as:

```
[
 {id: "5d0GSzovaSekAnHirJyjZ5hob202",
  reports[
         {county: "Laois", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...},
         {county: "Clare", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...},
         {county: "Cork", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}
         ]
  },
  {id: "IIqnl2Ff1VZQ5bv7qsLPnuhqlC03",
  reports[
         {county: "Kerry", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}
         ]
  },
  {id: "zspHtczidfVfjgWF6mPJKMfwvjy2",
  reports[
         {county: "Kilkenny", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...},
         {county: "Louth", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}
         ]
  }
```

Using this function below, I can push each element into an array to use nicely as a data source for the Mat table, but the problem is - I end up losing my UID.

```
this.reports.forEach(element => {
    this.finalReports.push(...element.reports);
  });
```

Output of finalReports array, which I currently display in the table:

```
[
{county: "Laois", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}, 
{county: "Clare", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...},
{county: "Cork", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...},
{county: "Kerry", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...},
{county: "Kilkenny", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...},
{county: "Louth", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}
]
```

I'm looking for a way to store the UID which each element belonged to alongside the data in the finalReports array, so it is easy to use as a MatTableDataSource - and also easy to delete from Firebase. I plan to ignore the UID in the search/filter functionality by using `filterPredicate()`.

The layout of the MatTableDataSource I'm looking for is this:

```
[
 {id: 5d0GSzovaSekAnHirJyjZ5hob202, report: {county: "Laois", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}}, 
 {id: 5d0GSzovaSekAnHirJyjZ5hob202, report: {county: "Clare", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}},
 {id: 5d0GSzovaSekAnHirJyjZ5hob202, report: {county: "Cork", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}},
 {id: IIqnl2Ff1VZQ5bv7qsLPnuhqlC03, report: {county: "Kerry", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}},
 {id: zspHtczidfVfjgWF6mPJKMfwvjy2, report: {county: "Kilkenny", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}},
 {id: zspHtczidfVfjgWF6mPJKMfwvjy2, report: {county: "Louth", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2", ...}},
]
```

That way I can use it like so in the table,

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.reports.county}}</td>
```

and hopefully, this will work when deleting...

```
***Home.ts***

<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><button mat-raised-button 
(click)="deleteReport(row)">Delete</button></td>

***firebase.service.ts***

deleteReport(row){

this.db.collection('newLayout').doc(row.id).update({
  "reports": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(row.report)
});
```

An example of the MatTableDataSource layout and `filterPredicate()` function I want to use can be seen in this `stackblitz` here: [Mat table stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-6o5ukn?file=app/app.component.ts)

Any help, thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't `this.finalReports.push(...element.reports)` be `this.finalReports.push(...this.reports)` ?

Comment: Just gave it a go @Maryannah, it just creates a big array with the entire "reports" array in it three times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will give you hopefully the result you are searching for

```js
private mapReports(reports: any) {
    const finalReports = [];
    reports.flatMap(entry => finalReports.push(...entry.reports.map(report => ({id: entry.uid, ...report}))));
    reports = finalReports;
}
```

It will give your a result like this

```
{id: 20, county: "Tipp", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2, ..."}
```

> Edit

If you want to have reports in its own object you can remove the spread operator:

```
.flatMap(entry => finalReports.push(...entry.reports.map(report => ({id: entry.uid, report}))));
```

Comment: Thanks a million! You saved me. That's very close result to what I had in mind - so I was able to make it work. I'll look up some `flatMap()` examples to try grasp it. 

Just out of curiosity, is it possible to alter your function to make the result like so, with the report as an object? 
`{id: 20, report: {county: "Tipp", dateAdded: "06-10-19 21:2, ..."}}`
It works anyhow, it would just be tidier in the delete function to pass the report object in.

Comment: That is absolutely perfect. Thanks a million.